# Options not parse as Argument in Unix

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopts

I has an existing script which works on $1 $2 $3, etc. I want to add an optional argument without disturbing the order.

Do we have some ready made solution for: 
*If a valid option (using getopts) is found, this index of argument should not be considered as argument.*

Comment: Hmm, not quite clear - can you provide a snippet? as described you would simply check for "$4" - but you would always call the script with your new argument in the 4th position...  If getopts in use then that may make a difference (i.e. the script 'barfs' on your new option with an error.

Comment: Check the number of options? 

    `if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then ...; elif [ $# -eq 4]; then ...; else ...; fi`

Although it's bound to be brittle.

Comment: Reasons for downvote please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual solution is to use `getopts` to scan and process the optional flag options, and then execute the command:

```
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

When `getopts` finishes, `$OPTIND` will be the number of the first as-yet-unprocessed argument. The `shift` command then deletes the first `OPTIND-1` arguments, which effectively renumbers the unhandled parameters to `$1`, `$2`,....

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach when *not* using getopts is to loop until the first non-option item is seen:

```
while [[ $1 = -* ]]; do
  # handle $1 here
  shift
done

foo=$1
bar=$2
baz=$3
```

If your option takes an argument itself (`--directory /somewhere`), then you simply need to `shift` an extra instance.

Comment: Nice, but the phrase "takes more options itself" is a little confusing; what an option takes is not another _option_, but an [option] _argument_.